# Show that $\delta(\xi-x)=\delta(x-\xi)$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

How would you show  $\delta(\xi-x)=\delta(x-\xi)$ if you know that 
$$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)h(x)=h(0)$$

Also how would you then show more generally that if $f(\xi)$ is a monotonic increasing or decreasing fuction of $\xi$ which vanishes for $\xi=x$ then,

$$\delta[f(\xi)]=\frac{\delta(\xi-x)}{|f'(x)|}$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HINT: strict monotonicity implies the function is invertible, and try to use change of variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question: let $u = \xi-x$, for any test function $h$
$$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(\xi - x)h(\xi) d\xi = \int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(u)h(u+x)du = h(u+x)\big|_{u=0} = h(x)$$
Try using the change of variable for 
$$\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x - \xi)h(\xi) d\xi$$
See if you get the same result.

For the second question, here I just show the general result for $f$ is monotonic increasing: For any smooth test function $\varphi$
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\delta[f(\xi)]\varphi(\xi)d\xi = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\delta[f(\xi)]\frac{\varphi(\xi)}{f'(\xi)} f'(\xi)d\xi
$$
Apply changing variable $u = f(\xi)$, notice that the limits of the integral do not change, i.e., $f(-\infty)=-\infty$, and $f(\infty)=\infty$ (for decreasing function limits are reversed):
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\delta[f(\xi)]\frac{\varphi(\xi)}{f'(\xi)} f'(\xi)d\xi = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\delta[u]\frac{\varphi(f^{-1}(u))}{f'(f^{-1}(u))} du
$$
$u=f(\xi) =0$ when $\xi= x$, hence:
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\delta[u]\frac{\varphi(f^{-1}(u))}{f'(f^{-1}(u))} du = \frac{\varphi(f^{-1}(0))}{f'(f^{-1}(0))} = \frac{\varphi(x)}{f'(x)}
$$
this tells us:
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\delta[f(\xi)]\varphi(\xi)d\xi = \frac{\varphi(x)}{f'(x)}
$$
Also notice
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\delta(\xi-x)}{f'(x)}\varphi(\xi)d\xi = \frac{\varphi(x)}{f'(x)}
$$
for any test function $\varphi$ too. Therefore
$$
\delta[f(\xi)] = \frac{\delta(\xi-x)}{f'(x)}
$$
when $f$ is monotonic increasing. When $f$ is decreasing, the proof is exactly the same except there is an extra minus sign in front, but you know $f'<0$, so an absolute value is added.